# Servet: Receive JSP File does not exist in WebContent

Tags: eclipse, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I'm using Eclipse to program servlet. Now, I want to make a `example.jsp` does something like servlet ( access attribute or parameter of ServletConfig, ServletContext,...)

I put example.jsp in top of WebContent, and the project name is ProjectExample.

In web.xml, here is how I declare this servlet:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JSP Example</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>example.jsp</jsp-file>  
    <init-param>
      <param-name>name</param-name>
      <param-value>hqt</param-value>
    </init-param>
// I meet warning at <jsp-file>: that doesn't found this file 
//although I have change to: `/example.jsp`, `ProjectExample/example.jsp` or `/ProjectExample/example.jsp`
</servlet>
```

Because Container doesn't recognize this file, so when I use: `getServletConfig().getInitParameter("name")` I will receive null !!!

Please tell me how to fix this.

Thanks :)

@: if something typing wrong in code, that not a problem because it's just typo. I don't know why StackOverFlow doesn't allow Copy/Paste function anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is not in your configuration, but rather the way jsp pages are configured.

Change your `<jsp-file>/example.jsp</jsp-file>` and add this to JSP:

```
Who am I? -> <%= getServletName() %>
```

On my box output is:

```
Who am I? -> jsp
```

That is because all JSP share the same servlet configuration called "jsp". It is configured at $CATALINE_HOME/conf/web.xml (if you are using Tomcat). For my Tomcat 7 that configuration looks like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Note: This is tomcat specific, other servers might work differently

Comment: Note: Eclipse will copy your $CATALINE_HOME/conf/web.xml to your workspace (in case you decide to remove jsp servlet and check what will happen)

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet should has the `init` method, there you can read the parameters you need:

```
public class SimpleServlet extends GenericServlet {
    protected String myParam = null;

    public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException{
        this.myParam = servletConfig.getInitParameter("name");
      }

    //your servlet code...
}
```

This example was taken from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html)